# Flutter : Dynamic DropDownButton get error (one item with [DropdownButton]'s value)

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdownbutton which get values from provider list as shown :

```
Consumer<OrderProvider>(builder: (context, orderProv, child) {
    print(orderProv.sizeList);
    return Container(
        width: 100,
        child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: orderProv.size,
            onChanged: (val) {
                orderProv.changeSize(val);
            },
            items: orderProv
                     .sizeList
                     .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((e) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: e,
                              child: Text(e),
                          );
                      }).toList()
        ),
    );
});
```

At the second line `print(orderProv.sizeList)`, when I print the dropdown menu list it prints the list correctly:

```
[S, M, L, XL]
```

But I receive the following error :

`There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value:  Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value`

Answer (score 0):

The value provided to the DropDownButton must be one of the values in the DropdownMenuItem. Please ensure that the `orderProv.size` points to one of the elements in the `orderProv.sizeList`.